# How do I insert developer buttons into a message box?

Tags: vba, radio-button, msgbox

I am trying to insert Optionbuttons into a msgbox in VBA. However, I cannot find the Optionbutton in the object browser. Below is my current **Incomplete** code:

```
   MsgBox(ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes)
```

How would I type this up to get a Optionbutton to appear within this message box? Postscript, there is no Optionbutton on slide1 (I am trying to write this into the code and not simply click "OptionButton" from the developer tab.)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`MsgBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)? It only takes a string as input.

Comment: You would have to create your own form that looks like a message box.

Answer (score 0):

Message boxes are only used to display text message to user. You can custom his title, his icon and choose between some standard actions (ok, cancel, yes, no...) to register the user answer to the message that you display.

If you want to display an interface wich activate another macro, you will have to design a userform with at least one button. Then you'll be able to catch the click_event of this button and run your desired program from this event.

This article explains with more détails how userforms work and can be designed :
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html